# How to group and position graphics in echarts

Tags: echarts

I want to group graphic elements in echarts so that I can position them together. I am not having much luck as the docs are really not that good.

I currently have the following:

```
option = 
{
  "width": 400,
  "height": 300,
  
  "graphic": [
    {
      "type": "group",
      "left":200,
      "top":20,
      "elements":[
      {
        "type": "circle",
        "shape": {
          "cx": 0,
          "cy": 0,
          "r": 100
        }
      },
      
      {
        "type": "text",
        "style": {
          "text": "54%",
          "fill": "#aaa",
        }
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

Not sure if the "elements" within the group is correct as the API docs do not say what element to use. Except if I am misunderstanding the concept of group.

The origin of the text graphic is top left whereas for the circle it is the center of the circle. But the group is not positioned as define in left/top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use children instead of elements if graphic type is of **group**.

```
    {
  "type": "group",
  "left":200,
  "top":20,
  "children":[
  {
    "type": "circle",
    "shape": {
      "cx": 0,
      "cy": 0,
      "r": 100
    }
  },
  
  {
    "type": "text",
    "style": {
      "text": "54%",
      "fill": "#aaa",
    }
  }]
}
```